# How do I remove SSH key passphrases from being remembered by Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, ssh

Mac OS X (Snow Leopard).

I accidentally selected the "remember password in my keychain" option when providing the ssh private key passphrase when connecting to a remote server.

Now, when I ssh to the server (even after reboots) it never prompts for the passphrase.  How do I get it to prompt me again?

-M

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open up Keychain Access (in /Applications/Utilities/), locate the SSH key (try typing SSH into the search box), right click and choose "Delete".